# Webpack using bootstrap - jquery is not defined

Tags: jquery, webpack

```
import $ from 'jquery';
require("./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
require("./node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js")
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var _ = require('lodash');
```

Please refer above my setting . Some reason I've got error saying "**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined()** from dropdown.js

I also included the following lines at webpack.config.js

```
   plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
]
```

But, No luck - Still having jQuery undefined error. 
Any idea ? Can someone help this issue please?

Many thanks

Comment: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/696 MurhafSousli  good answer

Answer (score 115, accepted):

please use webpack ProviderPlugin, use global is not a good idea.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
       })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Just saved me from doing `window.jQuery = require('jquery')`

Comment: doesn't it load jquery everywhere ? Is there a way to set up jQuery only when doing an `import 'jquery'` ?

Comment: I just can't get this to work with VS.net 2017 and WebPack 2...even restarted the whole machine once to be absolutely sure node restarted.  A coworker doing an unrelated Aurelia prototype had the same exact issue with vs 2017 and webpack 2 as well, and this didn't work for him either, so he ended up having to hack around it.

Answer (score 25):

This will work!

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

instead of

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: this is the only way I got jQuery working as dependency for Kendo UI. Thank you

Comment: Didn't work for me. The one above has worked, though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39283602/541961

Comment: it is much better to use ProvidePlugin

Comment: @Taras : Perhaps, but this worked for me back then and it continues to help a few people today with peculiar cases. :)

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me after trying out a lot of other things in Laravel mix.

Comment: Could Jquery BE any harder to get to work with webpack? No. No it couldn't if it tried. I had to work though every solution on this page until I got to this one.

Comment: I'm using create-react-app, this solution works perfectly for me! Before this, I tried to load jquery with <script> in index.html to archive the same effect, which broke my app.

Answer (score 19):

global.jQuery did not work for me. But I found an interesting read here: http://reactkungfu.com/2015/10/integrating-jquery-chosen-with-webpack-using-imports-loader/

The basic idea is to use webpacks 'imports-loader'. Notice, though, that it's not installed by default, so first thing install (npm install --save imports-loader). And in webpack.config add to your loaders the following:

```
{ test: /bootstrap.+\.(jsx|js)$/, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window' }
```

After that just import jquery and bootstrap, or some other plugins extending on 'jQuery', as usually.

regards

Comment: Works. But I had to set the loader to 'import-loader'   Like :               { test: /bootstrap.+\.(jsx|js)$/, loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window' }

Comment: Did you mean to link back to this question, or to something else?

Comment: @sean-the-bean definitely didn't want to link back to this question, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the post ant corrected the link.

Answer (score 8):

In order for this code to work you must **RESTART Node** after the change:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
       })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @Ro don't forget to restart the node server, the changes to the webpack will otherwise not be taken into account.

I confirm that once these lines added and the server restarted the error vanishes.

With Bootstrap 4 an updated version of the webpack.config.js will look actually like this because of its dependency with Tether:

> ```
> plugins: [
> // ...plugins...
> new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
>   $: "jquery",
>   jQuery: 'jquery',
>   "window.jQuery": 'jquery',
>   tether: 'tether',
>   Tether: 'tether',
>   'window.Tether': 'tether',
> }),
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Install and use [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader) for individual Dropdown imports with **Bootstrap 4.0** and **Webpack 3**.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
       })
```

---

Plugin or Individual import: `require("./node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown")`

versus

Importing Bootstrap in its entirety:`require("./node_modules/bootstrap")`

---

References

- the Bootstrap 4.0 note on importing [individual Bootstrap plugins with webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/#importing-javascript)
- [xushao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39283602/2692915)
- [Bhavyanshu Parasher's blog](https://bhavyanshu.me/using-bootstrap-4-webpack-3-and-yarn-for-wordpress-theme-assets/01/21/2018)

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
plugins: [ 
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery", 
           jQuery: "jquery"
     })
]
```

It worked for me hope it helps

Comment: Miss: const webpack = require("webpack");