# JQuery for Bootstrap does not loaded properly with WebPack and Angular2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, webpack

I spent on this lots of hours already with zero luck.

I need to use Bootstrap js which requires jQuery. It seems to me that both these libraries loaded (at least I can use $ in console), but jQuery and jquery reference in Chrome console do not work. My package.json

```
            {
              "name": "myproj",
              "version": "0.0.0",
              "description": "myproj",
              "private": true,
              "cacheDirectories": [
                "node_modules"
              ],
              "dependencies": {
                "@angular/common": "2.4.4",
                "@angular/compiler": "2.4.4",
                "@angular/core": "2.4.4",
                "@angular/forms": "2.4.4",
                "@angular/http": "2.4.4",
                "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.4",
                "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.4",
                "@angular/router": "3.4.4",
                "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.15",
                "angular2-cookie": "1.2.6",
                "angular2-infinite-scroll": "0.2.9",
                "jquery": "^3.1.1",
                "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
                "bootstrap-sass-loader": "^1.0.10",
                "codemirror": "5.23.0",
                "core-js": "2.4.1",
                "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
                "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
                "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
                "ng-jhipster": "0.1.6",
                "ng2-webstorage": "1.5.0",
                "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
                "rxjs": "5.0.3",
                "sockjs-client": "1.1.1",
                "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
                "tether": "1.4.0",
                "webstomp-client": "1.0.3",
                "zone.js": "0.7.6"
              },
              "devDependencies": {
                "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
                "@types/node": "7.0.1",
                "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.33",
                "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "1.0.2",
                "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.26",
                "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.0",
                "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.0.0-beta.18",
                "bootstrap-loader": "^2.0.0-beta.20",
                "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
                "browser-sync": "2.18.6",
                "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "1.1.3",
                "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.4",
                "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
                "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
                "del": "2.2.2",
                "event-stream": "3.3.4",
                "exports-loader": "0.6.3",
                "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.5",
                "file-loader": "0.9.0",
                "generator-jhipster": "4.0.1",
                "html-webpack-plugin": "2.26.0",
                "image-webpack-loader": "3.1.0",
                "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
                "jasmine-reporters": "2.2.0",
                "jquery": "^3.1.1",
                "karma": "1.4.0",
                "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
                "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
                "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
                "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
                "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.2",
                "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.4.0",
                "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
                "karma-webpack": "2.0.1",
                "lazypipe": "1.0.1",
                "lodash": "4.17.4",
                "map-stream": "0.0.6",
                "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
                "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.14",
                "protractor": "4.0.11",
                "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "0.3.2",
                "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
                "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
                "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.1",
                "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
                "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
                "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
                "string-replace-webpack-plugin": "0.0.5",
                "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
                "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
                "ts-node": "1.7.1",
                "tslint": "4.3.1",
                "tslint-loader": "3.3.0",
                "typescript": "2.1.5",
                "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
                "webpack": "2.2.0",
                "webpack-dev-server": "2.2.0",
                "webpack-merge": "2.4.0",
                "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.10",
                "write-file-webpack-plugin": "3.4.2",
                "yargs": "6.6.0"
              },
              "engines": {
                "node": ">=6.9.0"
              },
              "scripts": {
                "lint": "tslint src/main/webapp/app/**/*.ts --force",
                "lint:fix": "tslint src/main/webapp/app/**/*.ts --fix --force",
                "tsc": "tsc",
                "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
                "start": "npm run webpack:dev",
                "webpack:build": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js && webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js",
                "webpack:build:dev": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js",
                "webpack:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js  --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060",
                "webpack:prod": "npm test && webpack -p --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js && webpack -p --config webpack/webpack.prod.js",
                "test": "npm run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js",
                "test:watch": "karma start --watch",
                "e2e": "protractor src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js",
                "postinstall": "webdriver-manager update && npm run webpack:build"
              }
            }
```

my webpack.common.js

```
            const webpack = require('webpack');
            const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
            const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
            const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
            const StringReplacePlugin = require('string-replace-webpack-plugin');
            const AddAssetHtmlPlugin = require('add-asset-html-webpack-plugin');
            const path = require('path');

            module.exports = function (options) {
                const DATAS = {
                    VERSION: JSON.stringify(require("../package.json").version),
                    DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: options.env === 'dev'
                };
                return {
                    entry: {
                        'polyfills': './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
                        'global': './src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css',
                        'main': './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
                    },
                    resolve: {
                        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
                        modules: ['node_modules']
                    },
                    module: {
                        rules: [
                            { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery' },
                            {
                                test: /\.ts$/,
                                loaders: [
                                    'angular2-template-loader',
                                    'awesome-typescript-loader'
                                ],
                                exclude: ['node_modules/generator-jhipster']
                            },
                            {
                                test: /\.html$/,
                                loader: 'raw-loader',
                                exclude: ['./src/main/webapp/index.html']
                            },
                            {
                                test: /\.css$/,
                                loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                                exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
                            },
                            {
                                test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
                                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
                            },
                            {
                                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/i,
                                loaders: [
                                    'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                                    'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                test: /app.constants.ts$/,
                                loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
                                    replacements: [{
                                        pattern: /\/\* @toreplace (\w*?) \*\//ig,
                                        replacement: function (match, p1, offset, string) {
                                            return `_${p1} = ${DATAS[p1]};`;
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]})
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    plugins: [
                        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
                            names: ['manifest', 'polyfills'].reverse()
                        }),
                        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                            context: './',
                            manifest: require(path.resolve('./build/www/vendor.json')),
                        }),
                        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                            { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist', to: 'swagger-ui/dist' },
                            { from: './src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/', to: 'swagger-ui' },
                            { from: './src/main/webapp/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' },
                            { from: './src/main/webapp/robots.txt', to: 'robots.txt' },
                            { from: './src/main/webapp/i18n', to: 'i18n' }
                        ]),
                         new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                              $: 'jquery',
                              jQuery: 'jquery',
                              'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
                        }),

                        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                            template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
                            chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
                            inject: 'body'
                        }),
                        new AddAssetHtmlPlugin([
                            { filepath: path.resolve('./build/www/vendor.dll.js'), includeSourcemap: false }
                        ]),
                        new StringReplacePlugin()
                    ]
                };
            };
```

my vendor.ts

```
            /* tslint:disable */
            import '../content/css/vendor.css';
            import 'jquery'

            import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
```

I generated this project with jHipster and Angular2 support.

I get this exception in Chrome

```
            Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.dll.js:107411:9) [<root>] at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/vendor.dll.js:21:30)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack using bootstrap - jquery is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651015/webpack-using-bootstrap-jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

I just overcame the same problem.

It is because Webpack wraps the jQuery code as a module and stops the global variable from leaking, such as '$' and 'jQuery'.

The official has a guide for these problems relevant to the compatibility across AMD/CommonJS/global script. Check it out.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/

In short, I think webpack.ProvidePlugin is a good fix:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
],
```

---

Sorry, I missed you have configured Wepback to use ProvidePlugin. But in my side, I import BS3 as below to let Webpack resolve it to node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm:

```
import "bootstrap";
```