# How to integrate a external js into the main.js file in Webpack vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-4

I want to integrate a downloaded javascript file from the source folder.

Consider that the css and js files exists  in the path.

From what I gather to integrate a css in the `main.js` I just add

```
require('./vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

but how to add a js file ? When I add the js files the same way

```
require('./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js')
require('./vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')
```

I get an error message

```
./src/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/home/<cool path>/ClientVueJs/src/vendor/bootstrap/js'
 @ ./src/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js 14:125-142
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Comment: apparently bootstrap.bundle.min.js expects jquery. Try to instal it via npm and require it before bootstrap.

Comment: Do I add it to the `package.json` file and run npm install or how is jquery integrated. I thought that I already integrated the jquery file

Comment: I believe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651015/webpack-using-bootstrap-jquery-is-not-defined) is what your are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add alias for jquery to webpack config(and remove your `require` line `require('./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js')`), because bootstrap depends on 'jquery' module:

```
    module.exports = {
    //...
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                jquery: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js')
            }
        }
    };
```

This binding lets webpack resolve `require('jquery')` from bootstrap file.

If you need to map library to additional variables like `$` you have to use `ProvidePlugin`, check @Arseniy-II's comment with link.

Comment: I have added the allias line to my `webpack.base.conf.js ` file but I still get the error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in ',somepath./ClientVueJs/src'  @ ./src/main.js 24:0-17`

Comment: path should be relative to project directory, i think it should be `src/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js` in alias.