# $ is not defined when installing jQuery in Rails via Webpack

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to install jQuery in Rails 6.0.0.rc1 via Webpack and I'm not sure what I'm missing but I'm getting the error `$ is not defined` in the browser console despite being able to compile jQuery.

I've added jQuery with `yarn add jquery`, so my package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "muladeseis_app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

My app/javascript/packs/application.js is requiring jquery from node_modules

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
```

And I've tried to register `$` in config/webpack/environment.js by doing:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = environment

environment.plugins.append(
    'Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
)
```

Whenever I add a script in my views with a `$` reference I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

I've checked in StackOverflow answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651015/webpack-using-bootstrap-jquery-is-not-defined) to see if I'm registering incorrectly the key character '$' but I've found only answers suggesting using the ProvidePlugin which I'm already referring to in my configuration.

Also if I explore my app Sources in the browser inspector I do see jQuery code integrated in localhost:3000 >> packs/js so the issue is not that Webpack is not finding jQuery but that the key words '$' and 'jQuery' are not recognised.

I'd appreciate your help debugging this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've got what's missing.

In `app/javascript/packs/application.js` forgot to declare:

```
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

So jQuery keywords could be picked up.

Comment: Can you provide the full webpack config? Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The code in `config/webpack/environment.js` should look like this:

```
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)
```

see also https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/introducing-jquery-in-rails-6-using-webpacker

Comment: this doesn't work in `Rails 6.0.2.2` and yarn `1.16.0`

Comment: There is another solution with `expose-loader` which worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/54906972/2970582

Comment: This works for me (6.0.3.2).  Except - Why does only src work?  There is also a dist in the package but when I try that it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

I tried a lot of things and some worked and some didn't, and some didn't work in my Docker container. In the end I settled on putting this in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
global.$ = require('jquery')
```

You need to do `yarn add jquery` of course.

I'm sure there are better ways but this is the only thing that worked for me so I'm putting it up here in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Happy to help! I've since moved all of my JavaScript into packs so I no longer need this, but there are definitely situations where it is still required, such as when using older libraries that depend on jQuery being available globally.

Comment: Exactly, my use case is including ace editor to my app. It requires $ included globally. Thanks again

Comment: This broke something for me.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me with `Rails 6.0.2.2` and yarn `1.16.0`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54906972/2970582

Answer (score 1):

As I explained at https://github.com/rails/webpacker/commit/198a1580c7ec26a24ee81a09404fc173e725f032 and https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/3116defe:

1. Use `expose-loader` version 3
2. Prefer the inline version of exposing jQuery with `expose-loader` (documented at https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/#inline) by using `import $ from "expose-loader?exposes=$,jQuery!jquery"` in `app/packs/entrypoints/application.js`.
3. Where you use `javascript_pack_tag` add `defer: false`.  For example it could be in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` with:

````
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload',
      defer: false %>```
````

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to upgrade from rails 4 to rails 6.
After few hours of debugging , finally i fixed this jQuery loading error.

So here are the steps, I followed :

1. add jQuery

```
yarn add jquery
```

2. add expose-loader

```
yarn add expose-loader
```

3. update config/webpack/environment.js file

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.loaders.append('jquery', {
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    use: [{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: '$',
    }, {
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'jQuery',
    }],
});

module.exports = environment
```

4. update app/javascript/packs/application.js file

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require("jquery");
```

5. restart  webpack-dev-server

```
bin/webpack-dev-server
```

Always restart webpack-dev-server, if you update environment.js file.

if you want to use older version of jQuery (Ex: version 2.1.4 )

```
 yarn add jquery@2.1.4
```